# First slideshow image appearing slower than the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, delay

everyone. I have a slideshow that has the first slide appearing a second or two slower than the others. Here are the codes. Any idea why this is happening?

```
<ul class="slideshow home">
    <li><a href="fabrics/mulberryhome/mulberryhome_fabrics_bohemian_romance.htm">
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/fabrics/Bohemian-Romance2.jpg" alt="" />
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/fabrics/mulberryhome/HG-Fabric-Awards-Mulberry-1.png" style="position:absolute; bottom:35px; right:20px; width:85%; max-width:150px" /> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="wallcoverings/mulberryhome_wallcoverings_bohemian_romance.htm">
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/wallcoverings/Bohemian-Romance.jpg" alt="Mulberry Home Bohemian  Wallpapers" title="Mulberry Home Bohemian Wallpapers" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="carpet/leejofa_carpet_kensington.htm">
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/carpets/eastern-high-shine.jpg" alt="Lee Jofa Carpet Kensington" title="Lee Jofa Carpet Kensington" /> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="wallcoverings/coleson_wallcoverings_whimsical.htm">
            <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/wallcoverings/whimsical4.jpg" alt="Cole &amp; Son Whimsical"  title="Cole &amp; Son Whimsical" /> 
       </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="fabrics/leejofa/leejofa_fabrics_suzanne_kasler_collection_II.htm">
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/fabrics/suzanne-kasler-collection-II-C.jpg" alt="Lee Jofa Suzanne Kasler Collection II" title="Lee Jofa Suzanne Kasler Collection II" /> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="fabrics/groundworks/groundworks_fabrics_ashley_hicks_textures.htm">
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/fabrics/ashley-hicks9.jpg" alt="Groundworks Ashley Hicks Textures" title="Groundworks Ashley Hicks Textures" /> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="fabrics/leejofa/leejofa_fabrics_ithaka.htm">
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/fabrics/ithaka.jpg" alt="Ithaka Collection for Lee Jofa" title="Ithaka Collection for Lee Jofa" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="wallcoverings/groundworks_wallcoverings_david_hicks.htm"> 
           <img src="http://www.leejofa.com/images/wallcoverings/david-hicks1c.jpg" alt="David Hicks Wallpaper for Groundworks" title="David Hicks Wallpaper for Groundworks" /> 
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="fssList horizontal home"></ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx:        'fade',
    delay:    4000,
    timeout: 4000,
    pager:   '.fssList',
    slideExpr: 'li'
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you use this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ , right? For support, write to the Author or analyze its code. The answer should be there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation of the plugin you use, it seems to be the delay-parameter.
Set it to something small, like 10, and it will work like you expected.
delay seems to delay the start of the animation.

```
$(function() {
  $('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx:        'fade',
    delay:    10,
    timeout: 4000,
    pager:   '.fssList',
    slideExpr: 'li'
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://pascha.org/test/8.php)